# Really struggling with Paypal IPN

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

**Update - I removed the validation, and added an $item_id = $_POST['option_selection1']; to my field, and suddenly it worked!**

I have a website for a photographer, and she is selling time slots throughout the day.  I am trying to set her up so that someone chooses a time slot, purchases it through paypal, and then when the data is returned via IPN, I capture the email address used to make the purchase, as well as an id that I have associated with the time slot.  With that ID, I am setting a toggle in the database that causes that time slot to no longer populate on the form, so others can't purchase the same time slot.  Every time I make a test transaction, the database doesn't update, and I don't know why.  When I manually set the values of the variables $payer_email and $item_number, the database does what I would expect it to do.  From this, I'm under the impression that PayPal isn't validating the data, or it isn't sending the data in a way I'd expect it to.

Here is my code for the form that is running through PayPal:

```
   // Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT id,hour,minute,toggle FROM mini ORDER BY id ASC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
echo '<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="B6XDLRPVAUBQJ">
<input type="hidden" name="on0" value="item_number">
<select name="os0">';
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          if ($row["toggle"] == 0){ 
              echo '<option value="'.$row["id"].'">'.$row["hour"].':'.$row["minute"].' '; //id is what I'm trying to extract from paypal via IPN
              if ($row["id"] <  13){echo 'AM';}else{echo 'PM';}; //if-then statement determines if it is AM or PM based on id
              echo '</option>';
          };
     }
} else {
     echo "Sorry, I'm fully booked!";
}

?>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Book Your Session">
</form>
```

Here is my code for the IPN

```
<?php
// STEP 1: read POST data
// Reading POSTed data directly from $_POST causes serialization issues with array data in the POST.
// Instead, read raw POST data from the input stream. 
$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
  $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
  if (count($keyval) == 2)
     $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}
// read the IPN message sent from PayPal and prepend 'cmd=_notify-validate'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
   $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
} 
foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {        
   if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) { 
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value)); 
   } else {
        $value = urlencode($value);
   }
   $req .= "&$key=$value";
}

// STEP 2: POST IPN data back to PayPal to validate
$ch = curl_init('https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));
// In wamp-like environments that do not come bundled with root authority certificates,
// please download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set 
// the directory path of the certificate as shown below:
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem');
if( !($res = curl_exec($ch)) ) {
    // error_log("Got " . curl_error($ch) . " when processing IPN data");
    curl_close($ch);
    exit;
}
curl_close($ch);

// STEP 3: Inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
    // The IPN is verified, process it:
    // check whether the payment_status is Completed
    // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
    // check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
    // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
    // process the notification
    // assign posted variables to local variables
    $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
    $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
    $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
    $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
    $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
    $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
    // IPN message values depend upon the type of notification sent.
    // To loop thffrough the &_POST array and print the NV pairs to the screen:
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
      echo $key." = ". $value."<br>";
    }
} else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
    // IPN invalid, log for manual investigation
    echo "The response from IPN was: <b>" .$res ."</b>";
}

//database credentials intentionally omitted :)
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "UPDATE mini SET toggle='1',email='".$payer_email."' WHERE id=('".$item_number."')";


if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "<br/> - Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}


?>
```

Comment: Have you checked `error.log` in apache logs? (`/var/log/apache2/error.log` on most linux servers)

Comment: You should cut your code to bare minimum. Is the problem with curl not returning the desired data or not updating the db? Choose one and get rid of the excess noise.

Comment: Looking your code just a little bit, I see that you assign two different queries to `$sql` var without executing the first one.. Maybe that is your issue?

Comment: Are you using the IPN simulator? https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/ipn_simulator

Comment: Thanks for the questions...here we go.

I haven't checked the logs, and I'm with GoDaddy and it looks like that is disabled, so I'll enable it and once I get the logs I'll let you know.

I don't think curl is returning the data, because no information is reaching the database at all, and when I change the variables to a set value just before I begin parsing the data it works fine.

I am not using the simulator.  Try as I might, PayPal Developer wouldn't let me log into the account associated with this.  I've been using 0.01 cent transactions for testing.

Comment: Update: I checked the error log via the errors button in the cPanel, and it was empty.  I don't have an error.log file.

Comment: @JoaquínO - Silly me.  I fixed that, and retested to make sure the SQL works, and it does.  Now I just gotta figure out how to get PayPal to play nice, too.

Comment: Try without validating the data. With my experience PayPal sometimes sends you IPN with status "PENDING" or something.

Comment: @Lothar - I removed the validation, checked that the code ran, and it did.  I made a test transaction, and nothing happened.

I have a feeling that my form isn't correctly giving the data to PayPal

Comment: Oh I can notice you are not using sandbox... Is you application approved? Most probably your account is not fully enabled for production use.

Comment: Oh probably not.  Would that be why it's not validating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you to try using PaymentDetails API to debug the payment statuses that you are testing.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/PaymentDetails_API_Operation/

Also with PayPal sandbox is a little bit different, slower and buggier - so you should employ some logging. Log everything that is posted and the validation response. After having that you could focus on the app's logic.